# How to use haproxy for outgoing requests?

Tags: ssl, proxy, haproxy

I am trying to create a tls link between two haproxy instances. Each instance is installed on a machine which have some apps that need to talk with each other using the proxy. I want the haproxy instances to handle the tls stuff in behalf of apps since I am using client authentication. Now, what I tried to do is to have a haproxy on the client side to listen on localhost interface but it seems not possible. How do I accomplish that; to have outgoing/incoming going through haproxy ?

[image]

Comment: For simple TLS encapsulation, you may want to look also at `stunnel`. HAProxy can do it too of course but it is a more generic tool hence more options hence more things to understand or risks of being done wrong...

Comment: I have to use haproxy unfortunately due to policies where I work. Anyway, my question still stands, how to make the proxy capture the outgoing requests from the same host?